# Replace repeated code with an array and iterate through it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to replace some working but not optimal code, with an array that iterates through my elements.

Here's what I'm doing

```
$('.count0').keyup(function(){
    $('.counted0').text(this.value.replace(/{.*}/g, '').length );
});
$('.count1').keyup(function(){
    $('.counted1').text(this.value.replace(/{.*}/g, '').length );
});
$('.count2').keyup(function(){
    $('.counted2').text(this.value.replace(/{.*}/g, '').length );
});
$('.count3').keyup(function(){
    $('.counted3').text(this.value.replace(/{.*}/g, '').length );
});
```

and so on

What I want to achieve is something like
Find each `count` class, grab the text length from there, and put it inside a `div.counted`

How can that be achieved?

The markup is simple, like this:

```
<div>
  <input class="count">
  <div class="counted"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if the markup is that simple, you could try the following:

```
$(".count").on("keyup", function() {
    $(this).next(".counted").text(this.value.replace(/{.*}/g, "").length);
});
```

Comment: great, actually my markup is slightly different, sorry - it would be like <div>Char count: <span class"counted"></span></div>

Comment: Then you should use something like: `$(this).next("div").find(".counted")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.count').on('keyup', function(e){
    $(this).next('.counted').text(this.value.replace(/{.*}/g, '').length );
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRVYa/)